# Arduino HC-05 Master/Slave

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, master-slave

I am trying to be able to click a button on a tablet i have, and it sends a message to a master Arduino. The master Arduino then sends a message of to 4 slave devices, which switches on a relay. So far I have already been able to connect a HC-05 to an android and switch a relay on from that same Arduino but, now i need to expand it. I have about 10 HC-05 modules and i would like to use just them. Any help will be appreciated. I currently have pinched parts of the code from this website.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Remotely-Control-LED-using-HC-05-Bluetooth-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS

Thanks 
Ben

Comment: Do you have any questions or troubles with code or hardware?

Comment: Yes, how would I be able to receive a command from an android tablet and send a message to 4 Slave modules, all from one arduino?

Comment: You can use broadcasting, look at this post [Bluetooth broadcasting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674102/bluetooth-broadcasting)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into AT commands for the HC-05. They will allow you to set the connected device and send information to that specific device (which would permit the switching between slaves). I also go through basic switching with the HC-05, a relay, and an Arduino Uno on my blog.

https://engineersportal.com/blog/2017/11/15/bluetooth-home-automation-light-bulb-switch-using-an-hc-05-a-relay-and-arduino